# Printing org.joda.time.Period objects in a nice way

Tags: jsf-2, jodatime, omnifaces

I've an entity that contains a `org.joda.time.Minutes` field. I want to use that field in one of my `<h:selectOneMenu>` components as a label:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{manager.spec}"
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.choose_one}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{allSpecs}" var="spec" 
        itemLabel="#{f.print(spec.timeout.toStandardDuration().toPeriod())}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

With `f` (just a demo name, obviously) being:

```
@Named("f")
@RequestScoped
public class UserPeriodFormatter {
    private PeriodFormatter printer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        printer = PeriodFormat.wordBased(Faces.getLocale());
    }

    public String print(ReadablePeriod period) {
        return printer.print(period);
    }
}
```

This prints, eg. `5 minutes`, `1 hour and 10 minutes` or `3 months, 2 hours and 5 minutes`, using words from the user's locale.

My question is simply: is there a better way to do this? I tried a simple Producer method for the formatter, but since `PeriodFormatter` doesn't expose a no-arg constructor this won't fly with CDI.

Bonus question: could this be a nice addition to the omnifaces' dates functions?

Comment: At ZEEF we're using [OcpSoft PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) for this. Addition to OmniFaces would be hard because that would require a lot of reinvention of the wheel because we don't want to have any dependencies.

Comment: @BalusC Mhh, I've to look at this again. From what I've seen the only "jsf native" way is to attach a converter. But I've never done this to a `itemLabel` and have no clue how I'd go about it. Plus the converter accepts only `Date` objects. Getting them from a duration isn't going to be pretty (no pun intended).